# Tracking clicks in Google Analytics, no clicks registered on dashboard

Tags: google-analytics

I am tracking clicks by using the following JS in the link:

```
onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'External Link', 'Buy Link', 'Wind Jacket 5917'])"
```

However I am not picking up this in Google Analytics intelligence events. Is this the correct place to see these clicks?

I'm able to see clicks through a third-party affiliate dashboard but I am not seeing any clicks in GA.

My GA script is in the header and looks like this:

```
<script>
              (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
              (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
              m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
              })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

              ga('create', 'UA-12345678-1', 'auto');
              ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For tracking your event clicks, you are using the classic GA syntax, but in your GA snippet, you are using Universal Analytics. You will need to update the event tracking code to the UA syntax:

```
onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'External Link', 'Buy Link', 'Wind Jacket 5917');"
```

Comment: Thanks! This wasn't explained when I got the code snippet. Thanks for your help.

Comment: As a followup, do you know where these are viewable on the GA dashboard?